# Text Input Real time JS validation as Float which accepts floating point and comma

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate an input in real time way.
The input has type text and must validate only an input having :  number(s) and/or floating point or comma.
Also the input accepts only two numbers after the floating point/comma.
Examples :

- 12.23    Valid
- 12,23    Valid
- 12.2      Valid
- 12,02     Valid
- 2                Valid
- 12.035  Invalid
- 12.36E Invalid
- test         Invalid

**EDIT :**

Since I did not find the solution on stack and spent some hours to develop a solution that can help others i'll share what i've done :

I used the RegExp pattern to validate the number.but i can't do it with one pattern so i've created two patterns.
The first validates: x*.yy
And the second validates: x*,yy

Constraints : isNumeric doesn't accept float with comma.so that's why i've converted it.

The function validation function code :

```
function validateCurrencyPattern(price){
    var patt = new RegExp(/[0-9]+[.]{1}[0-9]{2}/i);
    var convertedPrice =price.replace(',', '.');
    var matchedString = price.match(patt)  ;
    var matchedString2 = convertedPrice.match(patt)  ;
    if (matchedString) {
        return matchedString
    }
    if (matchedString2) {
        return matchedString2
    }
    if((!$.isNumeric(convertedPrice))|| convertedPrice<0){
        return null;
    }
    else if(!matchedString && !matchedString2){
      return  convertedPrice;

    }
}
$(document).on("keypress keyup blur","#field", function (event) {
 $(this).val(validateCurrencyPattern($(this).val()));
});
```

and The call for function mixing the events (keypress keyup blur)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="field" name="field" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"/>
 <input type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest tracking the live input validation with a `/^(\d*)([,.]\d{0,2})?$/` regex that allows typing any 0 or more digits at the start, and then an optional substring of `,` or `.` and then 0, 1 or 2 digits. If there is a match, re-format the value by replacing `,` with `.`. If there input value is not matched, replace it with the last good value (say, introduce a variable called `prevValue` for that).

Once you want to submit this value, you need to make sure the value is in the final format, that is, there should be no `.` at the end. To enable this, add a `pattern` attribute to your `<input>` and assign the `^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` regex to it. Here, it will already require 1+ digits at the start of the string, and then will match an optional substring of a `.` followed with 1 or 2 digits. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NFi5gW/1). Since the comma will get replaced with a dot, you need no `[.,]` pattern, `\.` is enough.

Also, it is a good idea to handle the input value change on `paste`.

```js
var prevValue = "";
var patt = /^(\d*)([,.]\d{0,2})?$/;

function validateCurrencyPattern(price){
    var matchedString = price.match(patt);
    if (matchedString) {
        prevValue = matchedString[1] + (matchedString[2] ? matchedString[2].replace(",", ".") : "")
        return prevValue;
    }
    else {
      return prevValue;
   }
}
$(document).on("keypress keyup blur paste","#field", function (event) {
 $(this).val(validateCurrencyPattern($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="field" name="field" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"/>
 <input type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! , this solution is cleaner and more powerful. I knew there were better solutions than mine because I don't have a lot of knowledge about regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find the solution on stack and spent some hours to develop a solution that can help others i'll share what i've done : 
I used the RegExp pattern to validate the number.but i can't do it with one pattern so i've created two patterns.
The first validates: x*.yy
And the second validates:  x*,yy
Constraints : isNumeric doesn't accept float with comma.so that's why i've converted it.

The function validation function code  :
and The call for function mixing the events (keypress keyup blur)

```js
function validateCurrencyPattern(price){
    var patt = new RegExp(/[0-9]+[.]{1}[0-9]{2}/i);
    var convertedPrice =price.replace(',', '.');
    var matchedString = price.match(patt)  ;
    var matchedString2 = convertedPrice.match(patt)  ;
    if (matchedString) {
        return matchedString
    }
    if (matchedString2) {
        return matchedString2
    }
    if((!$.isNumeric(convertedPrice))|| convertedPrice<0){
        return null;
    }
    else if(!matchedString && !matchedString2){
      return  convertedPrice;

    }
}
$(document).on("keypress keyup blur","#field", function (event) {
 $(this).val(validateCurrencyPattern($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field" name="field">
```

Feel Free to optimize this solution or suggest another alternative that may be better than the existing solution.